# How can I have a duplicated row to show only one row with the most recent updating of the the table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new at PostgreSQL and I am building a new project where I need to work mostly on database. I have a table called `products` and I have filled it with some data. The problem here is that I need to find all the duplicated rows on the table. The table is like this:

```
id   |   name   | created_date  | updated_date  |
-----|----------|---------------|---------------|
1    | hat      | 01/05/2022    | 01/06/2022    |
2    | jeans    | 01/05/2022    | 01/06/2022    |
3    | shoes    | 01/05/2022    | 01/06/2022    |
4    | hat      | 01/05/2022    | 01/06/2022    |
...
```

The duplicated rows are `1` and `4` with the name `hat`.

After finding the duplicated rows, I need to display the row with the most recent date and then update the table where the table is filled without any duplicates.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to add an "expected result" set for the sample data you provided, so that the readers would know what you exactly consider to be "duplicates"

Comment: What exactly is a "duplicated _column_"? The same value in two different columns of the same row? But that would only work between columns of the same type. Which column (or did you mean rows?) in your example do you consider a "duplicate"?

Comment: Sorry, it was late at night when I posted. I mean rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DISTINCT ON (keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) *
FROM products
ORDER BY name, updated_date DESC
```

In this query rows with same name sorted by updated_date and all rows except first (with most recent date) are eliminated.